# Wordpress. Меню категорий (виджет) в сайдбаре переходит на новые страницы

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Сайт stockwood.by 
Страница "Каталог". Виджет для вывода категорий товаров xo10 woocommerce categories widget. При переходе в меню на категории/подкатегории выполняется переход на другую страницу, как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагин WooCommerce Product Filter (WOOF), который вы используете, имеет режим ajax. Включите его в настройках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О том, что категории в сайдбаре слева выводятся плагином WooCommerce Product Filter, я вижу по разметке в dev tools.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте.xo10 woocommerce categories widget - плагин, который я использую.

Comment: Я смотрю на разметку html в dev tolls и вижу woocommerce product categories

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но я имел ввиду меню в сайдбаре слева, а не фильтры.

Comment: @AlexBorisevich какое меню? Покажите на картинке. А в целом ответ такой - смените плагин, который выводит меню без ajax

Comment: @AlexBorisevich у вас нет никакого меню слева, есть только аккордеон с категориями, которые раскрываются по плюсикам. Добавил картинку в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У вас все правильно работает: нажимаешь на плюсик - открывается меню, нажимаешь на категорию - открывается страница с категорией с открытым меню. Вы хотите динамическую подгрузку контента? Тогда вам нужен не Wordpress, а отдельно API на бэкенде и single page application на фронтэнде. Возможно есть плагины для Wordpress, которые так умеют, но это жуткие костыли и нужно, считайте, сделать все заново.

PS. В перезагрузке страницы в вашем случае вообще нет ничего плохого. Визуально переходы по категориям воспринимаются некомфортно, потому что страница грузится очень долго и по частям.

Comment: Вы если ничего не слышали про ajax, который в WordPress сплошь и рядом, то уж не рассуждайте про костыли.

Comment: Ну ок, дизайн-студии виднее (без сарказма)